# W3 Error Validation Errors

Tags: html

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Home-International Student Home Page</title>
<link href="cssstyle.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>

<h3>About Image:</h3>
<p>Monroe College Logo</p>



<h1><a href="http://www.monroecollege.edu:">
<img src="monroelogo.jpg"  alt="" height="115" width="700"/></a> 
</h1>   

<h2>International Students Association</h2>


<!-- Top navigation -->
<div class="nav" align="center">
<a href="Homepage.html">Home Page</a>|
<a href="International Student Community.html">International Students Community</a>| 
<a href="Form.html">Registration Form</a> |  
<a href="Scholarship.html">Scholarships</a>|
 </div
```

I am having problems with these errors. Can someone please assist me with this issue. The codes below are the Error messages from W3 Validator:-

Info: The Content-Type was text/html. Using the HTML parser.

2.Info: Using the schema for HTML with SVG 1.1, MathML 3.0, RDFa 1.1, and ITS 2.0 support.

3.Warning: Empty heading.

From line 15, column 1; to line 15, column 4

go

↩↩↩↩

4.Error: The align attribute on the div element is obsolete. Use CSS instead.

From line 23, column 1; to line 23, column 32

ation -->↩↩

5.Error: Bad value International Student Community.html for attribute href on element a: Illegal character in path segment: not a URL code point.

From line 25, column 1; to line 25, column 47

Page|↩Intern
Syntax of URL:Any URL. For example: /hello, #canvas, or http://example.org/. Characters should be represented in NFC and spaces should be escaped as %20.

Comment: Asking for a little help okay, but you're just spitting out every message you got and ask us to solve it. All of these messages have clear descriptions and boil down to basic HTML knowledge and common sense. By the way, only two of them are errors, one is a warning (well meant advice, that is) and the first two are just informational. This can be determined by reading the labels that say 'info', 'warning' and 'error.

Comment: whats your url anyway?

Answer (score 1):

1 and 2 just Info about your page

3 have Warning Because in `img` you must write a alt like `alt="logo"`

4 you must remove `align="center"` from `div` and add `margin-left:auto;` in css file in `nav` class

5 says in name file and url don't use spaces rename you file like this `International_Student_Community.html`

this page don't have any Error

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Home-International Student Home Page</title>
<link href="cssstyle.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>

<h3>About Image:</h3>
<p>Monroe College Logo</p>



<h1><a href="http://www.monroecollege.edu:">
<img src="monroelogo.jpg"  alt="logo" height="115" width="700"/></a> 
</h1>  

<h2>International Students Association</h2>


<!-- Top navigation -->
<div class="nav">
<a href="Homepage.html">Home Page</a>|
<a href="International_Student_Community.html">International Students Community</a>| 
<a href="Form.html">Registration Form</a> |  
<a href="Scholarship.html">Scholarships</a>|
</div>
</body>
</html>
```